# Golang Static folder path returns all files

Tags: go, static-files, mux

i have a this code to open static folder

```golang
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

but when i'm going to `/static` path it returns a list of files in this folder

eg

```
license.txt
logo.png
```

but i want to return a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add blank `index.html` in directory `./static/`, it will be rendered as blank page.

Something like this

```
<html>
<head><title>Nothing here</title></head>
<body><h1>Nothing here</h1></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @YusufYakubov a file server serves files and directories if you want custom behaviour you would need to make your own fileserver implementation

Answer (score 0):

vodolaz095's answer is the simplest, but if you really must do it in Go, you could wrap the `FileServer` to catch the specific case of a request for the root:

```
func noIndex(fs http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.URL.Path == "" || strings.HasSuffix(r.URL.Path, "/") {
            w.Write("")
            return
        }
        fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't catch requests for subdirectories without a trailing slash in the URL; to trap this you'd need a much more detailed custom implementation that was filesystem-aware to know what is a directory and what is a file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `gorilla/mux` - but if you don't mind using the standard library's `http.ServeMux` you can achieve this in `Go` code like so:

```
func main() {

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
    h := http.NewServeMux()

    blank := http.HandlerFunc(func(_ http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {})

    h.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs)) // will match "/static" with a redirect ...
    h.Handle("/static", blank)                             // ... unless you create a hanlder explicitly

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", h)
}
```

from [http.ServeMux](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux) docs:

> ...if a subtree has been registered and a request is received naming
> the subtree root without its trailing slash, ServeMux redirects that
> request to the subtree root (adding the trailing slash). This behavior
> can be overridden with a separate registration for the path without
> the trailing slash. For example, registering "/images/" causes
> ServeMux to redirect a request for "/images" to "/images/", unless
> "/images" has been registered separately.